# AJAX call success but throws Undefined index error in $_POST['sample']

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call that passes data to another php file, `createTest2.php`, as below.

But the `createTest2.php` file throws error

```
Notice: Undefined index: sample in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestProj\Test\createTest2.php on line 2
```

caller.php

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#button_submit").click(function() 
 {

  $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"createTest2.php",
  data:{sample : "test"},
  success:function()
  {
    alert("success");
  }
});
});
});
```

createTest2.php

```
  <?php
       $test_name = $_POST['sample'];
       echo $test_name; 
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any javascript error in console?

Comment: I dont have any error. Only this Notice: Undefined index: sample in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestProj\Test\createTest2.php on line 2

Answer (score 2):

Total stab in the dark here but I'm guessing you have something like this

```
<form action="createTest2.php">
    <!-- some elements here -->
    <input type="submit" id="button_submit">
</form>
```

In which case, you should prevent the default action on the button, eg

```
$("#button_submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // and the rest of your ajax code
});
```

What's happening is your form's default method is *GET* and it is submitting normally, thus `$_POST` isn't populated.

Ideally, you should never blindly accept user input. I'd start with some checks in your PHP file

```
if (!isset($_POST['sample'])) {
    http_response_code(406);
    throw new Exception('sample data not submitted via POST');
}
$test_name = $_POST['sample'];
```

Secondly, catching click events on form submit buttons is rife with problems. For one, there's more than one way to submit a form. You should catch the form's *submit* event instead, eg

```
<form id="myForm" action="createTest2.php">
    <!-- etc -->
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

and the JS

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post(this.action, { sample: 'test' }).done(function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks.. i try ur code. I will response after I finish editing my code. ^ ^

Comment: Error found in your code Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_response_code() in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestProj\Test\createTest2.php on line 10

Comment: @EkimTrusher [`http_response_code()`](http://php.net/manual/function.http-response-code.php) is only available from PHP 5.4. See [this comment](http://php.net/manual/function.http-response-code.php#107261) for a backfill function for legacy PHP versions

Comment: ohh.. that's why. Thanks. But My problem still exsist. :( .. I try my best but only output empty but wen i alert the pass value it will success. I also use firebug if it have an error but no error found. how can I solve this issue. for me to proceed o another problem. this problem my my brain CRY. :'(